# How to convert Active Directory path to Java provider Url?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I have a ldap connection which is written on .Net.

```
DirectoryEntry ldapCon = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://OU=PS,OU=PR,OU=Users & Workstations,DC=PPETR,DC=COM");
```

I need to use this connection in Java-Jndi, for this reason i need a ldap url, which is like :

```
e.g. "ldap://10.0.0.1:389"
```

In that moment i need to convert ***"OU=PS,OU=PR,OU=Users & Workstations,DC=PPETR,DC=COM"*** to a url.

I've tried something like :

```
Hashtable<String, String> ldapEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>(11);
            ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "LDAP://OU=PS,OU=PR,OU=Users & Workstations,DC=PPETR,DC=COM");
```

but it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need host/ip and port information of the LDAP server. ldap://<HOST>:<PORT>/<BASE DN>